# Am I abusing the concept of a property settor by having the property datatype not match the data type of the corresponding field?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, properties, setter

I have a class that represents an rtf document `ClsRtfDoc`.

Instantiating an `ClsRtfDoc` object reads an rtf file and it first parses the rtf file to obtain various rtf file metadata.

For example, I have a field `int paperHeight` that I use to store the rtf file paper height parsed from the string that holds the rtf file contents.

Since the rtf file content is in a string variable, the `PaperHeight` property data type is a string and the `PaperHeight` property `setter` parses the paper height from the string blob (e.g., look for `\paperw12240\paperh15840` and grab 15840 from the blob), converts it to an integer, and sets the `paperHeight` field to the integer value. See code below.

I constructed the code this way because I want to isolate the parse + set operation. Am I abusing the concept of a property settor by having the property datatype not match the data type of the corresponding field? 
Is there a better practice (design pattern?) I should be using in constructing this code?

**CODE**

```
public partial class ClsRtfDoc
{
    int paperHeight;

    public string PaperHeight
    {
        set
        {
            MatchCollection objPaperHeight = Regex.Matches(value, "(\\\\paperw\\d+)(\\\\paperh\\d*)");

            if (objPaperHeight.Count >= 1 && objPaperHeight[0].Groups.Count == 3)
            {
                if (!(Int32.TryParse((objPaperHeight[0].Groups[2].Value).Replace("\\paperh", ""), out int paperHeightValue)))
                {
                    throw new FormatException("Can't find paper height");
                }
                else
                {
                    paperHeight = paperHeightValue;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new FormatException("Can't find paper height");
            }
        }
    }

    // CTOR
    public ClsRtfDoc(string fqFRtfFileName)
    {
        string rtfTextFromFile = GetRtfFromFile(fqFRtfFileName);
        PaperHeight = rtfTextFromFile;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might go into "opinion based" which is off topic, but I would never assume a property called `PaperHeight` would want an actual RTF document into itself and process it somehow. That's not what setters are for for me. That requires a method `ParsePaperHeight` or something. Especially since there's no getter this isn't a property.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized there is nowhere to code `get => paperHeight` (that makes sense anyway).   I think implementing `ParsePaperHeight ` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the best way of implementing such kind of logic for many reasons. The most obvious one is that, your class have many reasons to be changed, thus, violating the Single Responsibility principle. I suggest you create a "parsing" service that do the job for you, and then hand the output to the `ClsRtfDoc`. Because as its name suggest, `ClsRtfDoc` represent the document after getting parsed into an actual `ClsRtfDoc`.
For example, a proper `ClsRtfDoc` might look like this:

```
public class ClsRtfDoc
    {
        public int PaperHeight {get;set;}
        public ClsRtfDoc(int paperHeight)
        {
            this.PaperHeight = paperHeight;
        }
        public void AddPaper(){
            //Do something
        }
        public void RemovePaperAt(int index){

        }
    }
```

An example of "methods" that you might expect seeing on `ClsRtfDoc` object is `AddPaper`, or `RemovePaperAt`. But the parsing service, in the other hand, might look something like this:

```
public interface IClsRtfDocParser
{
    ClsRtfDoc ParseFromFile(string filePath);
}
public class ClsRtfDocParser:IClsRtfDocParser
{
    public ClsRtfDoc ParseFromFile(string filePath)
    {
        int paperHeight = 0;
        //After reading the metadata, you reach the paper height line or something like that
        MatchCollection objPaperHeight = Regex.Matches(value, "(\\\\paperw\\d+)(\\\\paperh\\d*)");
        if (objPaperHeight.Count >= 1 && objPaperHeight[0].Groups.Count == 3){
            if (!(Int32.TryParse((objPaperHeight[0].Groups[2].Value).Replace("\\paperh", ""), out int paperHeightValue)))
            {
                throw new FormatException("Invalid file format");
            }
            else
            {
                paperHeight = paperHeightValue;
            }
        }
        return new ClsRtfDoc(paperHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed (with equal credit to Sami Kuhmonen for basically the same observation)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say you're abusing it since the setter converts it to the correct data type. It is probably not best practice. If i were you i'd make a method that did what you had in the setter and just leave the setter to set the Int value but I don't think what you have is "Wrong".